# Extreme buffer size consequences

Tags: linux, kernel, compiler

What are the consequences of allocating and then populating an extremely large buffer in C? Can a stack have a maximum size and if so what are the security mechanisms that enforce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the consequences of allocating and then populating an extremely large buffer in C?

If a process grows excessively large in virtual memory it can result in [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

> Can a stack have a maximum size and if so what are the security mechanisms that enforce this.

This question has been asked and answered here: [how does the linux kernel enforce stack size limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561333/how-does-the-linux-kernel-enforce-stack-size-limits)

Related: [Linux Stack Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270945/linux-stack-sizes)

From the [`getrlimit` and `setrlimit` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html):

> **RLIMIT_STACK**
>
> This is the maximum size of the process stack, in bytes.  Upon reaching this limit, a SIGSEGV signal is generated. To handle this signal, a process must employ an alternate signal stack ([sigaltstack(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html)).
>
> Since Linux 2.6.23, this limit also determines the amount of space used for the process's command-line arguments and environment variables; for details, see [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

The limits such as RLIMIT_STACK are enforced by the kernel:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The getrlimit() and setrlimit() system calls get and set resource
>   limits respectively.  Each resource has an associated soft and hard
>   limit, as defined by the rlimit structure:

```
       struct rlimit {
           rlim_t rlim_cur;  /* Soft limit */
           rlim_t rlim_max;  /* Hard limit (ceiling for rlim_cur) */
       };
```

> **The soft limit is the value that the kernel enforces for the corresponding resource.  The hard limit acts as a ceiling for the
>   soft limit: an unprivileged process may set only its soft limit to a
>   value in the range from 0 up to the hard limit, and (irreversibly)
>   lower its hard limit.  A privileged process (under Linux: one with
>   the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability) may make arbitrary changes to either
>   limit value.**
>
> The value RLIM_INFINITY denotes no limit on a resource (both in the
>   structure returned by getrlimit() and in the structure passed to
>   setrlimit()).

Comment: That has cleared many things up. Many thanks for your excellent response